# how to parse the file value and store them into array in ksh

Tags: shell, scripting, ksh

Hi  am trying to store the file value into array like below

Fil.Txt has below value.. 
101, 5

102, 6

103, 7

I want to store them in array in ksh and want to print the same.. please help.

Do we have any two dimension array in ksh??

Comment: I agree with https://google-styleguide.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/shell.xml in avoiding arrays. I agree with you using ksh. Do you reaaly need to store them, can you process them right away? Something like `cat Fil.txt | tr -d "," | while read x y; do`

Answer (score 0):

```
awk -F, '
{
printf("    Code %s  %s\n",$1,$2)
r[NR] = $1
c[NR] = $3
```

}

```
 END { for(i = 1; i <= NR; i++) printf("  %s Record Count   %s\n", r[i],c[i])
```

}' totalsum.txt